# put a css shape inside a button of a submit form

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I wanted to put a CSS Shape inside a button for a submit form, I failed at start because I tried to somehow put the css shape inside  `<input type="submit">` But I had to use the html tag `<button>` instead... this was my solution and puts a nice pure css search icon in your search button. It might need a little adjustment though

```css
#search-icon {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.4em;
  height: 0.4em;
  border: 0.1em solid #B10B14;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
}
#search-icon::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.25em;
  bottom: -0.1em;
  border-width: 0;
  background: #B10B14;
  width: 0.35em;
  height: 0.08em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="search-field" />
  <button type="submit" id="search-icon-container">
    <div id="search-icon"></div>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do u want to use div for this? a button would do it right?

Comment: html has `button` tag

Comment: You can style the input tag exactly the same way you style a div.

Comment: if I use `input type="button"` somehow the ::before element from the CSS Shape doesn't work, i'll update with the CSS

Comment: html has `input` tag and `button` tag

Comment: All that matters is you set the type of your input to be "submit".  Then you can style it however you want, even adding background image, ...input[type="submit"] { background: url(...); position: etc.... }

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that you may also use font awesome ?

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/font-awesome/info

```css
button i {
  color:red;/*set the color */
  font-size:2em;./* set the size */
  }
/* even add some text decoration */
i:before {
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```